# asp:Table long text wrapping

Tags: css, asp.net

Below is my code in aspx file;

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Table ID="tblAssump" CssClass="tbl-assump" runat="server">
            <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="tbl-top-header">Items</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="tbl-top-header">Assumptions and Justifications</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>
            <asp:TableRow CssClass="tbl-row-assump">
                <asp:TableCell>1</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>RBI assessment is based on the HULL RBI Methodology, Doc. No.: GTS-RBI-FSTR-2015-R-002, Rev. 0 which has been approved by CLIENT.</asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow CssClass="tbl-row-assump">
                <asp:TableCell>2</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>Tagging methodology and rule of thumb:<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;i.&nbsp;From aft to forward - by framing number.<br />&nbsp;ii.&nbsp;From port to starboard - by longitudinal number.<br />iii.&nbsp;From bottom keel to upper deck - by elevation and/or longitudinal<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; number.</asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow CssClass="tbl-row-assump">
                <asp:TableCell>3</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>Component setup are based on typical type of structural component used for Hull construction. Risk is eing assessed for all possible tagged components (component system, NOT global system).<br /><br />Definition of Lower, Middle and Upper Zone shall reflect client's requirement, if not the appointed consultant shall advise accordingly.</asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and this is my CSS code;

```
.div-assump {
    float: left
}

.tbl-row-assump td:nth-child(1){
    vertical-align: middle
}

.tbl-row-assump td:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: red;
    max-width: 500px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-wrap: normal;
    text-align: justify
}
```

For some reason when I run the aspx file, the website result is like this;

[image]

Is there something wrong with my CSS table?

Comment: The problem is not in the above snippet. When I tested it, the sentences in the table were spread across multiple rows like you would expect.

Comment: I test on both Chrome and IE11... still the same as above problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the property of `white-space: normal;` or `word-break: break-all;` i think it will be work..

Comment: This work exactly like I want... Thanks you.

As clarification: word-break: break-all; will break all alphabet which mean the break might occurs in the middle of word.

Comment: white-space works to me, using AspNet MVC with .NET 6.0